# $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, does $\sum (a_n + \cdots + a_n^n)$ converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely. Does this imply that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n + \cdots + a_n^n)$$ converges?

I believe the answer is yes, but I can't figure out how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify? Is this a sum $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n^n$ or something else?

Comment: No, its $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^n a_n^m$.

Comment: @Karolis: No, it's $(a_1) + (a_2 + a_2^2) + (a_3 + a_3^2 + a_3^3) + \ldots$.

Comment: @mixedmath precisely

Comment: Very nice problem! (+1)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After a while, $|a_k| \lt \frac{1}{2}$.

From that point on, 
$$|a_k+a_k^2+a_k^3+\cdots +a_k^k| \le |a_k|+\frac{1}{2}|a_k|+\frac{1}{4}|a_k|+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}|a_k|\le 2|a_k|.$$
So by comparison our series converges absolutely.

Comment: Nice thanks.   ${}$

Comment: @André Nicolas: i wanted to post the same answer when i saw it. Now i think of a different approach. (+1)

Answer (score 7):

Another way to see this is to notice that each term is less than $a_n + a_n^2 + a_n^3 + ...$ which, when $a_n < 1$ is $\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$. When $a_n < \frac{1}{2}$ then $\frac{a_n}{1-a_n} < 2a_n$.